# how to remove the padding and margin to set of tables using bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

How to remove the padding and margin between textbox and td for the set of tables which has `column1` and `column2` in the header. I want to reduce the space.

Also how to put vertical scroll only if the table has more than 5 rows.

Please help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="panel-group">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading  text-center" style="background-color:red;color:white;">Sources</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <table class="table table-bordered" style="border:2px solid green;">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Column1</th>
                                            <th>Column2</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr style="border:2px solid brown;">
                                            <td style="border:2px solid brown;">
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="border:2px solid brown;">
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                    <tfoot>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>

                                                <a href="#">
                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                                                </a>

                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tfoot>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <table class="table table-bordered">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Column1</th>
                                            <th>Column2</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                    <tfoot>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <a href="#">
                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                                                </a>

                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tfoot>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <table class="table table-bordered">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Column1</th>
                                            <th>Column2</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                    <tfoot>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>

                                                <a href="#">
                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                                                </a>

                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tfoot>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <table class="table table-bordered">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Column1</th>
                                            <th>Column2</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />                                                </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                    <tfoot>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>

                                                <a href="#">
                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                                                </a>

                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" size="10" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tfoot>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help how to do this formatting. I am just trying to make it compact with less space between column border and textbox